# Timed out Exception in Mongodb using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following Java code to save new entry to MongoDB if the entry is not in DB. I run it in Java Timer for every 2 seconds.

```
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("testdb");

        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("testcollection");

        // Search for existing entries

        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("link", entry_url);

        DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
        try {
            // If it is a new entry, insert
            if (cursor.hasNext() == false) {
                // Insert new entry
                BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("link", entry_url)
                        .append("a_time", accept_time).append(
                                "p_time", formatter.format(date));
                coll.insert(doc); 
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

The problem is after several minutes, there is a `com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]` from mongoDB. It refers to `cursor.hasNext()`. Any suggestions for this problem?

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=Unknown, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=Unknown, state=Connecting}]
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:396)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:569)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:370)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:623)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:494)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:621)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:657)
```

The Timer implementation

```
         try {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new STimer(), 0, 2 * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Based on the comments below, I closed the mongoClient connection. Problem solved.

Comment: Where is the Java Timer implementation? I think you need to ensure to close the mongoclient also

Comment: @Shervin, I just edited the post. Thanks for your suggestion to close the mongoClient connection.

Comment: Great! I will change the comment to answer, and then you can accept it so its easier to see what the answer is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also ensure MongoClient is properly closed